# Pythonic argument passing

Tags: python, methods, arguments

Which one of these two method invocations is considered most pythonic?

```
some_method(that_has, very_many, aurguments=None, of_different=None, 
            kinds=u'', and_importance=None, spanning=u'multple lines'):
```

or

```
method_args = {
   u'first_arg' : that_has,
   u'second_arg' : very_many,
   u'arguments' : None,
   u'of_different' : None,
   u'kinds' : u'',
   u'and_importance' : None,
   u'spanning' : u'multiple lines'
}
some_method(**method_args)
```

Personally I prefer the second when the first spans more than 2 lines and the first way if it fits in one line, for two lines I am not quite certain.

**Edit**: The passed arguments might not be as short and static as in my example, more likely to be quite long names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a static call like that, the above is more Pythonic. If you want (and some people actually do this) you can align it like this:

```
some_method(
    that_has,
    very_many,
    arguments=None,
    of_different=None, 
    kinds=u'',
    and_importance=None,
    spanning=u'multple lines'
)
```

Also note that your second way doesn't even work - it only passes keyword arguments (to arguments that might not even be keywords).

Comment: my laziness might have made it a bit unclear, what I had in mind is a generic case, not necessarily static like this one

Comment: But the concept works, you just need a separate tuple for positional arguments.

Comment: @nightcracker would you say aligning one per line is better when you cant fit them all on two lines?

Comment: @ib.lundgren: not at all, I personally use word wrap so I almost never format function calls myself.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is more readable.

Once you reach a certain level of complexity for a function's arguments, it can be worthwhile to actually define a class which encapsulates those arguments:

```
args = SomeMethodArgs() # custom args class for the some_method func

args.x = 2
args.y = "a string"
args.z = None
args.items = [a, b, c]

some_method(args)
```

This has the benefit that you can modify the number of arguments or the signature later on in one place with minimal collateral effect.